# Javascript - Values appearing before expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, console.log, hoisting

I'm doing some string manipulation by splitting the string using `.split('')`, then iterating through it with a `for` loop, then using `.join('')` to reassemble it. I coded the split, loop, and join, and everything worked fine. But I decided to do another for loop operation on the string before the loop I already had, but after the split, and I ran into this. Before I even get to the loop, those values are showing up in the array! What is going on?

Here's a sample program showing the problem stripped to bare bones.

```
var someFunction = function () {
    var foo = '';

    foo = foo + 'Hello, world!';

    console.log(foo);

    console.log(foo.split(''));

    foo = foo.split('');

    console.log(foo); //  <-- This is the call causing me issues

    for(var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
        foo[i] += 'bar';
    }

    foo = foo.join('');

    console.log(foo);
};

someFunction();
```

This outputs:

```
Hello, world!
Array(13) [ "H", "e", "l", "l", "o", ",", " ", "w", "o", "r", … ]

Array(13) [ "H", "e", "l", "l", "o", ",", " ", "w", "o", "r", … ] //<-- This is the marked console.log call

    [
    0: "Hbar"    //<-- This is the array expanded so you can see the values inside
    1: "ebar"
    2: "lbar"
    3: "lbar"
    4: "obar"
    5: ",bar"
    6: " bar"
    7: "wbar"
    8: "obar"
    9: "rbar"
    10: "lbar"
    11: "dbar"
    12: "!bar"
    ]

Hbarebarlbarlbarobar,bar barwbarobarrbarlbardbar!bar
```

It's really stumping me!

Comment: The console evaluates the content of the array when you expand it. If you want to see the content at the time of execution use `console.log(JSON.stringify(foo))`

Comment: When you log an object (such as an array) with `console.log`, the log keeps a reference to the object. If you expand the object in the log later, you see its contents as they are **then**, not earlier when it was logged. See the linked questions' answers for details.

Comment: Just FWIW, if you want to add something after every character in a string, you don't have to `split`, `for`, and `join`, you can use `replace`: `"Hello world".replace(/./g, "$&bar")` results in `"Hbarebarlbarlbarobar barwbarobarrbarlbardbar"`.

Comment: Interesting. So I could workaround it using ```console.log(JSON.stringify(foo))```, like Andreas said, or I could store ```foo``` in an intermediate variable, and log that, like ```var fooSansBar = foo;```, then ```console.log(fooSansBar);```

Comment: No, you’d need to *copy* it into a new value, otherwise you just have two references to the same data.

Comment: @DaveNewton Wait, you're saying that ```var fooSansBar = foo;``` isn't storing the _contents_ of ```foo``` into ```fooSansBar```, it's still storing a reference to the current state of ```foo```?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I appreciate it! In the actual application, I'm not adding something after every character, I'm actually adding a random number of things after a random number of characters at random places in the string... but I'll keep that solution in mind for later!

Comment: @ToTheStars_1138 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copy-array-by-value

Comment: Aha! Wow, that is helpful to know, and probably explains hours of debugging pain I've previously undergone. Thank you everyone for your quick and helpful replies!